# Reading multiple CSV files object at once from AWS S3 using aws.s3 package

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I need to read multiple csv files from AWS S3 bucket with aws.s3 package in R and finally combine those files in single dataframe for further analysis.

Let' say I have several files in my S3 bucket like "variables_2019-08-12.csv" , "variables_2019-08-13.csv and "variables_2019-08-14.csv rtc.

I am using `aws.s3::s3read_using` but for `object` part I can only read one csv file each time. File has a date in their name so I was wondering how to add a loop in here :

```
my_file <- 
s3read_using(FUN = read_csv, object = "variables_2019-08-12.csv", bucket = "my_bucket")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this in R but the most intuitive for me is using [`map_dfr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) from the {purrr} package:

```
objects = c('variables_2019-08-12.csv', 'variables_2019-08-13.csv', …)
names(objects) = gsub('variables_(.*)\\.csv', '\\1', objects)
df = map_dfr(
    objects,
    ~ s3read_using(FUN = read_csv, object = .x, bucket = 'my_bucket'),
    .id = 'Date'
)
```

Because of the `names(objects)` assignment, and because we specify `.id = 'Date'`, the resulting data frame will have an additional column containing the date (based on the filenames) of each entry.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad , only one question if we have 100 csv files I am thinking to do  a loop like  `startdate=*_2019-08-15
enddate=*_2019-08-21
for(i in startdate:enddate) {....}` . Is it correct way to do so ?

Comment: Yes, That's correct. I just need to create a sequence of sting object + date to feed it into the object vectors. Great